# Why is zooming on mobile devices so finicky on my website?

Tags: angularjs, mobile

I'm having issues with my website on mobile devices. I've done everything I can find to enable zooming, and I've only been able to get it to work sporadically. Please help me!

I've tried using a meta tag a million different ways (user-scalable=1, user-scalable=true, playing with min and max, etc) and nothing seems to help.

http://blindvisionfilms.com/index.html

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that the issue I was having was with the quojs framework. It binds on body's touchmove event and if there are 2 fingers in the touch, then it prevents the default behavior. I realized that I'm only using one small part of the functionality so I'm now only using that small bit of code instead.

Answer (score 0):

Set the viewport to something more mobile friendly:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Remove the `min-width` from your body element.

Since you're using bootstrap: take a look at their [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and wrap your content in grid columns.

This will ensure that the layout responses correctly on a mobile.

Comment: I've tried that for my view port, and removing the min-width. This doesn't make the zoom any better. I'm aware that I could make the layout mobile responsive, but I really don't want to do that, I just want to make my users able to zoom.